# Python - Sending files over sockets

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have been trying to implement a small SERVER - CLIENT app but ran in to a errrr:

> socket.error: [Errno 10057] A request to send or receive data was
>   disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a
>   datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Server:

```
class Server:
    gate = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 0
    file = ''

    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        self.gate.bind((self.host, self.port))  
        self.listen()

    def listen(self):
        self.gate.listen(10)
        while True:
            add = self.gate.accept()
            self.reciveFileName()
            self.reciveFile()


    def reciveFileName(self):
        while True:
            data = self.gate.recv(1024)
            self.file = data

    def reciveFile(self):
        createFile = open("new_"+self.file, "wb")
        while True:
            data = self.gate.recv(1024)
            createFile.write(data)
        createFile.close()



a = Server(1111)
```

Client:

```
class Client:
    gateway = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #host = socket.gethostname()
    host = ''
    port = 0
    file = ''

    def __init__(self, host, port, file):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.file = file
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        self.gateway.connect((self.host, self.port))
        self.sendFileName()
        self.sendFile()

    def sendFileName(self):
        self.gateway.send("name:" + self.file)

    def sendFile(self):
        readByte = open(self.file, "rb")
        data = readByte.read()
        readByte.close()

        self.gateway.send(data)
        self.gateway.close()



a = Client('93.103.56.251', 1111, 'data.txt')
```

Comment: One problem I've noticed of that python is your succession of infinite loops.

Comment: A side note, if you are into socket programming, you should check out the book "Foundation of Python network programming". It addresses your question rather nicely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A server has one server socket that is used to `accept` incoming connections, and another socket for each of these connections. From your code:

```
self.gate.listen(10)
while True:
    add = self.gate.accept()
    self.reciveFileName() # which calls self.gate.recv()
```

Instead of operating on self.gate in `reciveFilename` and `reciveFile` (by the way, the proper spelling is `receive`), you should make these methods operate on the [accepted](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) connection, like this:

```
def listen(self):
    self.gate.listen(10)
    while True:
        conn,address = self.gate.accept()
        self.receiveFilename(conn)

def receiveFilename(self, sock):
    buf = sock.recv(1024)
    print('First bytes I got: ' + buf)
```

Also, `reciveFilename` currently listens forever on the socket. Instead, you must design a proper protocol that specifies when the filename is over and the file content begins. For example, you can let the file name end with `b'\0'` and let the server search for that byte.

Comment: I tried passing accepted connection add to the other two functions but i cant use recv() on it. Can you please explain that better or show me a example.

Comment: If you want us to help you with your problem, you should elaborate why you *can't use `recv`* on it. Are you getting an exception? If yes, which one? Added an example of how to read from the socket.

Comment: It returns add : data = add.recv(4096)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recv'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nered\Documents\Python\source\server\Server.py", line 34, in <module>
    a = Server(1111)
  File "C:\Users\nered\Documents\Python\source\server\Server.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.listen()
  File "C:\Users\nered\Documents\Python\source\server\Server.py", line 23, in listen
    self.receiveFile(conn)
  File "C:\Users\nered\Documents\Python\source\server\Server.py", line 28, in receiveFile
    buf = sock.recv(4096)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'recv'

Comment: I had it written like that that is when i was getting this error.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. `accept` returns a tuple of socket and address. Updated the answer.

Comment: I noticed that only as much buffer as i provide as much is transferred. Since not all data would be of the same size is there a way to dynamically set the buffer size.

Comment: No, as I wrote in the answer, you must design a protocol that specifies the file length upfront, or alternatively read until you get an EOF (but then, you can't get the filename). [Iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iff) EOF is encountered, `recv` will return `''`.